# Facebook Style Messages: Efficient Query

Tags: mysql

```
users tbl:
id
username
first_name
last_name
email_address

messages tbl:
id
date_sent
title
content
status

message_relation tbl:
id
message_id
sender_id
receiver_id
```

What would be the most efficient way to query a message TO a selected user given these tables? In other words, I want to list all messages that are in userA's "inbox"

Secondly, how would you recommend handling global messages that need to be sent to everyone from the admin?

Comment: query a message to a user is not very clear, what does it mean

Comment: @Ibu, I added an extra sentence. It's just a standard query, but I want to see if there are differing ways of querying this.

Comment: how about the user table? it will make more sense to provide this 3rd table structure

Comment: @Ibu, I've added the users table.

Comment: Tip: I would suggest giving specific ID names to your tables, like Private_Messages.Message_ID as the Primary key instead of the somewhat ambiguous Private_Messages.ID

Comment: @babonk, I just know that "id" always refers to the table's incremented id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for..

```
SELECT [WHATEVER] FROM 
messages
INNER JOIN message_relation
 ON (messages.id = message_relation.message_id AND message_relation.receiver_id = $id)
```

This does what you asked for efficiently.  If you also want to select fields on either of the users, you can JOIN Receiver_ID to User_ID to to get that.

Suggested tables setup if you want Global/Admin messages:

```
Messages (Message_ID, [Fields common to all messages, e.g. Message_Content, Message_Timestamp, etc])
Global_Messages (Global_Message_ID, Message_ID, [any fields specific to Global_Messages])
User_Messages (User_Message_ID, Message_ID, [any fields specific to User_Messages])
User_Message_Relations (User_Message_Relations_ID, User_Message_ID, Sender_ID, Receiver_ID)
```

Then, to query an Inbox, something like:

```
SELECT [WHATEVER] FROM
Messages

LEFT JOIN (Global_Messages)
 ON (Messages.Message_ID = Global_Messages.Message_ID)

LEFT JOIN (User_Messages)
 ON (Messages.Message_ID = User_Messages.Message_ID)

LEFT JOIN (User_Message_Relations)
 ON (User_Messages.User_Message_ID = User_Message_Relations.User_Message_ID AND User_Message_Relations.Receiver_ID = $uid)
```

That will give you a result you can loop through to get a user's entire Inbox.

Comment: Because they're not actually "private" messages technically. These are messages that can be sent to one or all recipients. If they were 1 to 1, I'd have it all in a single table.

Comment: ok, i got you.  anyways, i think the query above should get all the messages received by a given user_id

Comment: How would you recommend handling global messages that need to be sent to everyone from the admin?

Comment: I would actually suggest a Global_Messages table for that.

Comment: Ah yes... and then a second global_message_relation/global_message_status table so that you can keep track of whether the message was read yet?

Comment: Check out my suggested setup.  Has the advantage of being normalized, so in the future you could create new Message tables like Private_Messages, etc

Comment: Awesome! I will check this out tomorrow and put it to practice. You've been a fantastic help!

Comment: Sure thing, just post a comment here if you have any trouble/questions

Comment: With the first `Left Join ... ON`, I get a "Column 'message_id' in field list is ambiguous" ... I'm pretty sure it's because I don't have the FK relationship set up properly. I think I need to change all of my tables engine to InnoDB, correct?

Comment: You're getting that error because you're not specifying the table_name.message_id.  But yes I would recommend using INNODB.. they are really better than MyISAM in every way, including allowing you to put on FK constraints

Comment: InnoDB for all tables? Or just tables that need FKs?

Comment: Use it for all tables.  It's better in every way

Comment: @babonk, can there be a table (or column in an existing table) that represents whether or not the message has been read or not? I'm thinking two, one for `user_messages` and another spot for `global_message`...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    m.id, m.date_sent,m.title,m.content,m.status
FROM 
    messages m
INNER JOIN 
    message_relation mr on (mr.message_id = m.id)
INNER JOIN
    users u on (u.id = mr.receiver_id);
WHERE u.id = ...your current user id ...
```

This is a simple way of doing it, and it will be fast and almost no load on your database

Comment: What if I needed to also display who it's from? Should there be a "from" in the initial messages table? Or is that something additional to query?

Comment: Also, how would you recommend handling global messages that need to be sent to everyone from the admin?

Comment: i guess you can add to the same query an Inner Join users u2 on (u2.id = mr.sender_id) make sure you add all the fields u need in the select part, such as firstname lastname ...

Comment: i would recommend adding another field to ur message table `type` to specify the kind of message, private or global. then you can test for the type when you are doing the query

Comment: I would advice against using an ENUM to structure your database.  Using a seperate table has the advantage of giving you a normal, expandable structure.  ENUMs should be reserved for real world data that occurs  in lists..